# Messaging Engine failed to register the adapter for "WCF-BasicHttp"

Tags: .net, iis, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010

> The Messaging Engine failed to register the adapter for "WCF-BasicHttp" for the receive location "/OrderProcessingDescription/OrderProcessService.svc". Please verify that the receive location exists, and that the isolated adapter runs under an account that has access to the BizTalk databases.

The service account in Application pool identity is also a member of Biztalk isolated host users.
I am still not able to get rid of this issue.

I am working on BizTalk Server 2010 and OS is Windows Server 2008

Comment: Have you made sure that you have the correct accesses in the actual database? Check the permissions using the Sql Management Studio.

Comment: @Riri Pl mention what permissions are needed.

Comment: Do you have a biztalk receive location configured (and enabled) with the WCF-BasicHTTP adapter selected with it's address set to "/OrderProcessingDescription/OrderProcessService.svc"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on UAT environment, whereas the same services TEST worked fine.

Solution was the IIS application pool identity didn't match the identity that the isolated host instance was running under

Changed the IIS identity, recycled and the deployment tests went green